# Concatenate fields using XML and XSLT in loop

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a source XML file that I want to convert into another XML file with a different format. My source XML file uses attributes (I think, correct me if I'm wrong here) and the target XML format should be plain parent-child XML tags. I have no issues with a straight forward approach.

However, I need to find a way to concatenate 2 or more fields into a single element using XSLT. I tried using variables then concatenating them however, I am having some issues with variables and they can only be assigned once.

My XML is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document xmlns="http://www.taleo.com/ws/integration/toolkit/2005/07" xmlns:ns1="http://www.taleo.com/ws/integration/toolkit/2005/07" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><Attributes><Attribute name="count">1</Attribute><Attribute name="duration">0:00:00.109</Attribute><Attribute name="entity">SourcingRequest</Attribute><Attribute name="mode">XML</Attribute><Attribute name="version">http://www.taleo.com/ws/tee800/2009/01</Attribute></Attributes><Content>
<ExportXML xmlns="http://www.taleo.com/ws/integration/toolkit/2005/07">
    <record>
        <field name="Title">Project Analyst</field>
        <field name="Position_ID">64057</field>
        <field name="RequisitionNumber">180767</field>
        <field name="LocationCode">HQ</field>
        <field name="LocationName">Headquarters</field>
        <field name="LocationCountry">Country</field>
        <field name="LocationCity">City</field>
    </record>
</ExportXML></Content></Document>
```

Then my XSL is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0" xmlns:itk="http://www.taleo.com/ws/integration/toolkit/2005/07">
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes" cdata-section-elements="DescriptionInternal DescriptionExternal QualificationExternal QualificationInternal"/>
  <xsl:template match="text()"/>
  <xsl:template match="itk:record">
    <xsl:element name="Job">
        <xsl:for-each select="itk:field">
            <!-- Set variables -->
            <xsl:variable name="location_code">
              <xsl:if test="@name='LocationCode'">
                <xsl:value-of select="." />
              </xsl:if>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:variable name="location_name">
              <xsl:if test="@name='LocationName'">
                <xsl:value-of select="." />
              </xsl:if>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:variable name="location_country">
              <xsl:if test="@name='LocationCountry'">
                <xsl:value-of select="." />
              </xsl:if>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:variable name="location_city">
              <xsl:if test="@name='LocationCity'">
                <xsl:value-of select="." />
              </xsl:if>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="@name='LocationCode' or @name='LocationName' or @name='LocationCountry' or @name='LocationCity'">
                <xsl:if test="@name='LocationCity'">
                  <xsl:element name="Location">
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat($location_code,$location_name,$location_country,$location_city)" />
                  </xsl:element>
                  <xsl:element name="LocationCode">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$location_code" />
                  </xsl:element>
                  <xsl:element name="LocationName">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$location_code" />
                  </xsl:element>
                </xsl:if>
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:otherwise>
                <!-- Set variables. -->
                <xsl:variable name="NodeName" select="@name"/>
                <xsl:element name="{@name}">                
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </xsl:element>                
              </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>             
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However, my output is like this:

```
<Job>
   <Title>Project Analyst</Title>
   <Position_ID>64057</Position_ID>
   <RequisitionNumber>180767</RequisitionNumber>
   <Location>City</Location>
</Job>
```

But my desired output should be like this:

```
<Job>
   <Title>Project Analyst</Title>
   <Position_ID>64057</Position_ID>
   <RequisitionNumber>180767</RequisitionNumber>
   <Location>HQ Headquarters Country City</Location>
</Job>
```

If my guess is right, I think the loop resets the values of variables. So whatever was last will be the value.

Is there any other way I can achieve the desired output. My options are limited to XSL although my source file can be changed into CSV format.

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason why you can't do simply:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:itk="http://www.taleo.com/ws/integration/toolkit/2005/07" 
exclude-result-prefixes="itk">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/itk:Document">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="itk:Content/itk:ExportXML/itk:record"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="itk:record">
    <Job>
        <Title>
            <xsl:value-of select="itk:field[@name='Title']" />
        </Title>
        <Position_ID>
            <xsl:value-of select="itk:field[@name='Position_ID']" />
        </Position_ID>
        <RequisitionNumber>
            <xsl:value-of select="itk:field[@name='RequisitionNumber']" />
        </RequisitionNumber>
        <Location>
            <xsl:value-of select="itk:field[@name='LocationCode']" />
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="itk:field[@name='LocationName']" />
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="itk:field[@name='LocationCountry']" />
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="itk:field[@name='LocationCity']" />
        </Location>
    </Job>    
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Or, if using XSLT 2.0, even simpler:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xpath-default-namespace="http://www.taleo.com/ws/integration/toolkit/2005/07" >
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/Document">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Content/ExportXML/record"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="record">
    <Job>
        <xsl:for-each select="field[not(starts-with(@name, 'Location'))]">
            <xsl:element name="{@name}">
                <xsl:value-of select="." />
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <Location>
            <xsl:value-of select="field[starts-with(@name, 'Location')]" />
        </Location>
    </Job>    
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I actually did get it to work I guess somewaht similar to this solution. I posted an answer a few minutes after this so marking this as the answer.

Comment: I may have missed something, but I don't see anything here that depends on XSLT 2.0.

Comment: @MichaelKay The last `xsl:value-of` retrieves 4 values with a separator. In XSLT 1.0 it would have returned only the value of `LocationCode`. In addition, there is no `xpath-default-namespace` in XSLT 1.0.

Comment: Thanks - didn't spot that!